# How can I subset a Seurat object so that it only contains multiple samples?

Tags: r, seurat

or anyone familiar with Seurat: How would I subset an integrated seurat object down to multiple samples? I was able to subset an object to 1 sample using 1 of the the group IDs as shown below. When I try to include multiple samples, it doesn’t work. Any suggestions?

```
#source: https://figshare.com/articles/dataset/Data_R_code_and_output_Seurat_Objects_for_single_cell_RNA-seq_analysis_of_human_breast_tissues/17058077?file=31546307
tnbc <- readRDS(“data/SeuratObject_TNBC.rds”)
tnbc.groups <- c(“TN_B1_0554",
            “TN_B1_0177”,
            “TN_B1_4031",
            “TI_B1_0131 ”
)
tnbc <- subset(tnbc, subset = group == tnbc.groups)
Warning message:
In group == tnbc.epi.TN.groups :
 longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Answer (score 0):

If `group` is a variable in the Seurat metadata, you should be able to subset like this:

```
tnbc <- subset(tnbc, subset = group %in% tnbc.groups)
```